# Trigger not firing for instead of insert SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to convert a value from varchar to varbinary.

The creation of the trigger is successful. However it is not firing against an insert query.

Trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER HashPassword
ON Users
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Users (Username, [Password], FirstName, LastName, RoleID)
        SELECT
            i.Username,
            CONVERT(varbinary(max), EncryptByPassPhrase('iskam_6_za_bazata_moje_i_za_springa', i.[Password]), 2),
            i.FirstName, i.LastName, i.RoleID
        FROM 
            inserted AS i
END
```

`Users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Users.RoleID] 
        FOREIGN KEY([RoleID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Roles] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Users.RoleID]
GO
```

I tried executing this query:

```
INSERT INTO Users (Username, [Password], FirstName, LastName, RoleID)
VALUES ('martini', 'parola', 'martin', 'atanasov', 4)
```

But the result was an error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: I would ask do you *need* to be able to decrypt these passwords? Your trigger says it's "hashing" them but it's not; hashing is one way. Why aren't you actually hashing and salting them (ideally in the application)?

Comment: @Larnu Yes I need to be able to decrypt them. I did not know the difference between hashing and encrypting so I named it hashpassword.

Comment: Aside, you really should not be storing passwords with reversible encryption - you should always hash a password and validate the hashed parameter with the stored hash.

Comment: Hashing is "one way"; once a value is hashed you should not be able to "unhash" it to work out what the value originally was. Encryption is designed to be 2 way; when you encrypt something you can use the key that was used to encrypt it to decrypt it, and get the original value. If you are storing the login credentials of a user, so that they can authenticate to the applicate, you should not need to be able to decrypt it. I, personally, doubt that you do infact need to decrypt these values; if you are then the users should at least be aware that **any** administrator can view their password(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert a varchar into a varbinary max column.  So this

```
INSERT INTO Users(Username,[Password],FirstName,LastName,RoleID)
VALUES('martini','parola','martin','atanasov',4)
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO Users(Username,[Password],FirstName,LastName,RoleID)
VALUES('martini', cast(N'parola' as varbinary(max)),'martin','atanasov',4)
```

Or you create a view on Users that performs the varbinary>nvarchar cast and put your instead of trigger on that.